# How could I remove the blank page before the title page?

Tags: titles, blank-page

I'm using latexian to edit my manuscript. However, the first page is blank. The following is my latex code. How could I deal with this problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
\title{paper}
\author[1*]{author A}
\author[1]{ author B}
\author[2]{author C}
\affil[1] {Department of A, University of ABC}.\\
\affil[2]{Department of B, University of CBA}.\\
\affil[*]{Corresponding author: abc@email.abc.edu}
\date{}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
content
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
content
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip for the future: You can make the code formatting by indenting four spaces or by clicking the `{}` button in the toolbar of the editor. This way all your line breaks will be preserved. By `\end{Introduction}` do you mean `\end{document}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some `.\\` after `\afil` commands that goes to the first page. Without the blank page is gone:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
\title{paper}
\author[1*]{author A}
\author[1]{ author B}
\author[2]{author C}
\affil[1]{Department of A, University of ABC}
\affil[2]{Department of B, University of CBA}
\affil[*]{Corresponding author: abc@email.abc.edu}
\date{}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
content
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
content
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]